# Setting default fallback for Zuul routing failures

Tags: spring, spring-cloud, netflix-zuul, hystrix, spring-cloud-netflix

We are trying to override the default error page you get when there is a routing failure within the Zuul Edge Server and aren't having any luck. We have routes set up like so:

```
zuul:
  routes:
    ui: /**
    api: /api/**
```

The default SendErrorFilter attempts to send the request to /error by default and that works when the ui service is up and running as it will serve up /error.  But the problem is when the ui server is down, it tries to route to /error and fails. You then get the big nasty exception on your screen saying there was a forwarding error and no fallback was available.

```
com.netflix.zuul.exception.ZuulException: Forwarding error
    org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.route.RibbonRoutingFilter.forward(RibbonRoutingFilter.java:140)
    org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.route.RibbonRoutingFilter.run(RibbonRoutingFilter.java:105)
    com.netflix.zuul.ZuulFilter.runFilter(ZuulFilter.java:112)
    com.netflix.zuul.FilterProcessor.processZuulFilter(FilterProcessor.java:197)
    com.netflix.zuul.FilterProcessor.runFilters(FilterProcessor.java:161)
    com.netflix.zuul.FilterProcessor.route(FilterProcessor.java:120)
    com.netflix.zuul.ZuulRunner.route(ZuulRunner.java:84)
    com.netflix.zuul.http.ZuulServlet.route(ZuulServlet.java:111)

Root Cause:
    com.netflix.hystrix.exception.HystrixRuntimeException: uiRibbonCommand failed and no fallback available.
    com.netflix.hystrix.AbstractCommand$16.call(AbstractCommand.java:807)
    com.netflix.hystrix.AbstractCommand$16.call(AbstractCommand.java:794)
    rx.internal.operators.OperatorOnErrorResumeNextViaFunction$1.onError(OperatorOnErrorResumeNextViaFunction.java:77)
    rx.internal.operators.OperatorDoOnEach$1.onError(OperatorDoOnEach.java:70)
    rx.internal.operators.OperatorDoOnEach$1.onError(OperatorDoOnEach.java:70)
    rx.internal.operators.OperatorDoOnEach$1.onError(OperatorDoOnEach.java:70)
    com.netflix.hystrix.AbstractCommand$DeprecatedOnFallbackHookApplication$1.onError(AbstractCommand.java:1516)
    com.netflix.hystrix.AbstractCommand$FallbackHookApplication$1.onError(AbstractCommand.java:1406)
    com.netflix.hystrix.HystrixCommand$2.call(HystrixCommand.java:314)
    com.netflix.hystrix.HystrixCommand$2.call(HystrixCommand.java:306)
```

How do you set a default Fallback in Zuul to handle these errors so the user doesn't see the nasty exception?  I have seen this [open issue on spring-cloud-netflix (#250)](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-netflix/issues/250), but I would deal with a default fallback for all routes, not just specific routes.  What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: Do you want a default fallback or a custom error? Because you mapped a default route `/**` you've lost `/error`.  You can turn off the error page via `server.error.whitelabel.enabled=false`. http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-actuator.html#howto-customize-the-whitelabel-error-page

Comment: We want to provide a custom 500 error html page. So I thought we could make a fallback that returns a view from the edge server, but can't figure out how.

Comment: fallbacks are not supported in zuul. You could write a post filter.

Answer (score 2):

Fallbacks are now supported in the latest release of Spring cloud.  Please review the post - [Fallback methods at Zuul server in Spring cloud](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37748378/fallback-methods-at-zuul-server-in-spring-cloud/40622638#40622638) 
for additional details

Comment: You should consider putting a version number to help direct the user to the right revision/version that solves their problem.

Comment: Thanks.. Check out spring cloud version 1.2.3.BUILD-SNAPSHOT

Comment: Thanks, we'll try to test this out